# How to remove the "locked" flag (programmatically)

Tags: zsh, attr

(MacOS Monterey):

I have external hard disks with files written under Windows, using Cygwin `rsync`.

The files are perfectly readable under MacOS, but when I want to delete/overwrite them, quite some appear "locked" (operation not permitted when doing a `rm`) on MacOS. Using the Finder, I can remove the lock by getting the context menu on the file, choose "GetInfo", and unchecked the *Locked* property.

But there are too many of them to do it by hand. I would like to run recursively over the file tree and uncheck the "locked" attribute programmatically. Of course the problem is not the traversal of the directory tree (can done by `find` for instance), but the change of the attribute from the command line.

`chmod` does not help here (as the files **are** 0777). Any other command I can use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found the command to do so:

```
chflags nouchg FILENAME
```

The command is described [here](https://ss64.com/osx/chflags.html)